# How to inflate different layout in RecyclerView based on its position in onCreateViewHolder method

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter, android-recyclerview

I am trying to refactor my ListView to RecyclerView and I stuck in this situation.

> In my ListView Adapter i have something like this:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (mDecommissionMode && position == getCount() - 1)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (getItemViewType(position) == 0)
        return getNormalView(position, convertView, parent);
    else
        return getManualDecommissionView(convertView, parent);

}
```

I don't have an idea how can I apply this to my RecyclerView adapter because **I don't have access to the position in onCreateViewHolder** method, where the layout should be inflated.

> Here are the methods in my RecyclerView Adapter:

```
@Override
public DevicesItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    DevicesRecyclerViewAdapter.DevicesItemViewHolder holder = new DevicesItemViewHolder(); //should pass some inflated view to ViewHolder instance
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mOnClickListener.onClick(view);
        }
    });
    return holder;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DevicesItemViewHolder holder, int position) {


}
```

Is there a way I can cope with it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create RecyclerView with multiple view type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type)

Comment: You want to have control in onBindViewHolder() right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Create Two View Holders for two Layouts

Follow these three simple steps

- Override `getItemViewType(int position)`
- Return different ViewHolders based on the ViewType in
  `onCreateViewHolder()`        method
- Populate View based on the itemViewType in `onBindViewHolder()`
  method (This solves the position problem you are facing)

Here is a small code snippet for RecyclerView Adapter
You can see the full code for reference [Here](https://github.com/rohitksingh/Gizli/blob/master/Gizli/app/src/main/java/com/rohksin/gizli/Adapters/VaultListAdapter.java)

```
public class YourListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private static final int LAYOUT_ONE= 0;
private static final int LAYOUT_TWO= 1;

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position)
{
    if(position==0)
        return LAYOUT_ONE;
    else
        return LAYOUT_TWO;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


    View view =null;
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

    if(viewType==LAYOUT_ONE)
    {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.one,parent,false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolderOne(view);
    }
    else
    {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.two,parent,false);
        viewHolder= new ViewHolderTwo(view);
    }

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {


    if(holder.getItemViewType()== LAYOUT_ONE)
    {

    }
    else {

        ViewHolderOne vaultItemHolder = (ViewHolderOne) holder;
        vaultItemHolder.name.setText(displayText);
        vaultItemHolder.name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                .......
            }
        });

    }

     
}



public class ViewHolderOne extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView name;
    
    public ViewHolderOne(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.displayName);
        
    }
}

public class ViewHolderTwo extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public ViewHolderTwo(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        
        ..... Do something
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In  your `Adapter` class put this

```
enum VIEW_TYPE {
VIEW1, VIEW2}
```

Then override `getItemViewType(int position)` in the adapter and return `VIEW_TYPE.VIEW1.ordinal()` or `VIEW_TYPE.VIEW2.ordinal()` based on your logic with the given `position`. And in the `onCreateView`, you'll get the viewtype value. Based on that return a `VieHolder` with the `View`